# Looking up and replacing column names

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(A=1, B=2, C=3)
new.names <- data.frame(old=c("A","B","C"), new=c("X", "Y", "Z"))
```

How can i look up `names(df)` in `new.names$old` and replacing them with `new.names$new`?

Desired output:

```
names(df)
[1] "X" "Y" "Z"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `plyr` package we could use `mapvalues` function

```
library(plyr)
df_new <- df
  colnames(df_new) <- plyr::mapvalues(colnames(df),
                                   as.character(new.names$old),
                                   as.character(new.names$new))
```

Output:

```
> df_new  
  X Y Z
1 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it could be:

```
names(df) <- new.names$new[match(new.names$old, names(df))]

  X Y Z
1 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways come to mind: base R and `data.table`. I changed the order of the names just to show that the look-up is working.

#### Base R

Instead of a data.frame with the names, I would use a named vector (using the old names as names of the components of this vector):

```
df <- data.frame(A=1, B=2, C=3)
new_names <- setNames(c("Y", "X", "Z"), c("B","A","C"))

names(df) <- new_names[names(df)]
```

#### `data.table`

More straightforward:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(A=1, B=2, C=3)
setnames(df, old = c("B","A","C"), new = c("Y", "X", "Z"))
# Note that setnames() doesn't return anything. You can 
# run names(df) for seeing the result.s
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- rename(df, !!invoke(set_names, unname(new.names)))
df
  X Y Z
1 1 2 3
```